# Veeam Powershell - Export results to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a script to gather the name of each backup / replication job and list the virtual machines in the job.

The following script works - to console output.
I have tried numerous methods to export to csv without any success.
Any ideas?

```
foreach($job in Get-VBRJob) {
  Write-Host "Job:", $job.Name;
  $job.GetObjectsInJob() | foreach { $_.Name }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Veeam's PowerShell Toolkit, but I'd expect something like this should work (provided the job object actually has a method `GetObjectsInJob()`):

```
Get-VBRJob | % {
  $job = $_
  Write-Host "Job:", $job.Name
  $job.GetObjectsInJob() | select @{n='Job';e={$job.Name}}, Name
} | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```